# Drupal 7 specific layouts for pages

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-zen

I am using drupal 7 and my theme is a sub-theme of Zen. What I am trying to do is on some specific pages /volunteers/bigbrothers the layout of this page needs to differ slightly than that of /volunteers.

I am sure this is stupid simple and maybe I'm not googling the correct search terms to find my answer. I'm just not sure what to look for exactly so i'm having a hard time with this.

I've used the page--front.tpl.php to override the homepage but can't seem to figure out how to do this for specific pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, template or .tpl.php is the overall direction.

There are node.tpl.php, block.tpl.php, or bigbrothers.tpl.php if you have custom content type called bigbrothers.

Also check [here](http://blog.drupalguru.com/ujval99/20101129/drupal-7-custom-templates-content-type)

Comment: i deleted my previous comment figured out my issue with the content type, the problem is the content type doesn't give me what i'm looking for, i'm looking for more of an override of page.tpl.php how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Assuming bigbrother is custom content type, if you want to change the layout of view node page you will need use `node--bigbrother.tpl.php`.if you want to change the layout of add/edit node page, you use the `bigbrother.tpl.php` as well as modify template.php. refer to first comment here [link](http://drupal.org/node/1039998)

Comment: the problem I have with the node approach is it's only working for the content area and not the entire page, should it be doing that?

Comment: sorry i am an idiot, i knew i was doing something stupid, needed to use page--bigbrother.tpl.php instead of node--bigbrother.tpl.php to override the entire page layout